# Is a good idea use Membership Provider with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, membership, membership-provider

In ASP.NET MVC we dont have Login controls of webform, then still make sense use Membership Provider? It is a good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Membership Provider is agnostic of Web Forms or any other classes where it will be used, so the least I can say is its not a bad idea.

Comment: I like to have control over the fields and the table names, for instance in my scenario I don't want to users to have to specify email, also I don't want it in a separate database, and many more reasons. How do I gain control over it. I want to create a simple EF-based membership provider that I create, that has User, Role and UserRole table. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The Membership Provider is just a data store, use it as you wish. There just happen to be ASP.NET forms controls that also know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it still makes sense.  Take a look a the default project created by Visual Studio (not the empty one), to see how it can be used with ASP.NET MVC and unit tests.